# jquery nested selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I grab the nested element "4"?

I tried:

```
var nights = $("div.nights h5 div.num").val();
```

and:

```
var nights = $("div.nights > h5 > div.num").val();
```

example:

```
<div class="nights">
        <h5 class="biguns">
            <div class="num">4</div>
            Nights
        </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) here instead, like this:

```
$("div.nights h5 div.num").text() // descendant selector
//or this works too:
$("div.nights > h5 > div.num").text() // child selector
//or just
$("div.num").text(); // chaining tag and class selector
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PXC6H/1/), as you can see above, your selector is flexible, use what works on your overall markup.  [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for input type elements, e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`, `<button>`...to get the text inside of any other element, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

Comment: ah, yes... i knew it was something so simple my brain was going to explode. thanks.

Comment: @nick Yaaa, great answer, can you please edit the answer and add what type of selector, in a comment

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div.nights  div").text()
```

but not

```
$("div.nights  > div").text()
```

because
descendant selector:
A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, and so on, of that element.
child selector:
 Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

reference [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)
[descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)